# Where can I find "Backgrounds" for D&D 4e?

Tags: dnd-4e

My DM wants me to pick a couple of backgrounds for my character for a 4e game.  Where can I find them?

Comment: If anyone could edit this question to briefly explain what a "background" is in this context, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One good source is the "Backgrounds section on this [page](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19648946/Holy_Smoke_A_Clerics_Handbook). It lists major sources and summarizes the mechanical implications of the backgrounds.

[DDI Character builder](http://wizards.com/dnd/Tool.aspx?x=dnd/4new/tool/characterbuilder) has a complete list and the demo is free.

Comment: It's worth noting that the Character Builder demo is at least two years out of date.  So it will not include content from the many books and articles that have been released since.

Comment: The links in this answer are now both broken. You may want to update it to, e.g., point at archived versions of the pages.

Comment: Should that first link should go [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20141103215035/http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/3084151) rather than to a cleric handbook?

Answer (score 5):

Many backgrounds are specific to a particular setting.  So the *Forgotten Realms Player's Guide*, *Eberron Player's Guide*, and the *Dark Sun Campaign Setting* each have a set.  If you're playing in a particular setting, ask to borrow the campaign guide to get access to the list.  That's probably the easiest route.

The various *X Power* books (*Martial Power, Primal Power, Psionic Power*, etc) include backgrounds relevant to the book's focus. The *Player's Handbook Races: X* books (e.g. *Player's Handbook Races: Dragonborn, Player's Handbook Races: Tiefling*) have backgrounds relevant to those races.  There are also some in the *Player's Handbook 2* and *3*, as well as the

Going through all of those books is difficult.  Many people use Dungeons & Dragons Insider to get the information, where it's all collected in one place.
If you have a D&D Insider account, the DDI Character Builder and the [D&D Compendium](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/tool.aspx?x=dnd/4new/tool/compendium) both offer a nearly complete list of backgrounds and will note which book they are originally from.  DDI is a bit expensive, so if you don't have an account, see if your GM does and ask to borrow him computer for a bit to browse the compendium.

Finally, if all of that is too complex, I recommend just telling the GM you want the Akanûl background from Forgotten Realms.  +2 resist cold, fire, and thunder.  Hard to go wrong with that. :-)

Comment: Of course, then you have to roleplay that your character hails from bleeding Akanul...

Comment: The link in this answer is now broken. You may want to update it to, e.g., point at an archived version of the page (or whatever may be appropriate).