# What are the available Adventurer's League eligible D&D 5e backgrounds, and where can I find them?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league, background

Similar to the [possible races](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77247/what-are-the-playable-dd-races-in-5e-and-where-can-i-find-them), [official classes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/125278/what-are-the-official-wotc-published-classes-and-subclasses-in-5e), and [4e backgrounds](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3567/where-can-i-find-backgrounds-for-dd-4e) questions, **what are official WotC-published backgrounds available for players, and which books/resources contain them?**

By *official*, I mean that the backgrounds are available for **Adventurers League Play**. While other backgrounds from Unearthed Arcana or from other WotC sources outside the D&D team are of interest, please mention whether they're considered official and sanctioned or not.

Comment: For AL-legality: do you specifically care about Forgotten Realms AL characters (as opposed to Eberron)?

Comment: @CTWind I didn't even realize there was a difference. I think any AL legal are fine, and a note mentioning if a background is specific to a setting would be perfect

Comment: Ah, ok- it's also worth noting there's backgrounds in official books that are not valid sourcebooks for D&D AL, then; as far as I know, the backgrounds in *Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica*, for example, cannot be used in any flavor of AL, even though it's an official D&D team book.

Comment: Related(?): "[What are all the background features in the Player's Handbook?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/162624)"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Current as of *AL Player's Guide v11.0*.

The *[Adventurers League Player's Guide](https://media.wizards.com/2021/dnd/downloads/DDAL_PlayersGuidev11_0.pdf)* covers what is a legal DDAL resource. From the *AL Player's Guide v11.0*:

> You can use non-optional rules found in the Player’s Handbook,
> the Basic Rules, and all the books listed below.

#### Eligible sourcebooks containing backgrounds:

- [*Basic Rules*](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf#page=22) (BR), Chapter 3: Classes
- [*Player's Handbook*](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/rpg_playershandbook) (PHB), Chapter 4: Backgrounds
- *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide*

#### Official D&D Adventure Products

- *Hoard of the Dragon Queen*
- *Rise of Tiamat*
- *Out of the Abyss*
- *Curse of Strahd*
- *Tomb of Annihilation*
- Ghosts of Saltmarsh
- *Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus*
- *Icewind Dale: Rime of the Frostmaiden*
- *The Wild Beyond the Witchlight*

#### D&D Adventurer's League and Guild Adept Products

- *Ruins of Mezro*
- *Rats of Waterdeep*
- *Durnan's Guide to Tavernkeeping*
- *Knuckleheads and Other Curiosities*

#### Premier Organizer Products

- *The Border Kingdoms*
- *Moonshae Isles Regional Guide*

---

#### Official Backgrounds from Sourcebooks

- Acolyte (BR,  PHB)
- Charlatan (PHB)
- Criminal (BR, PHB)
- Criminal Variant: Spy (BR, PHB)
- Entertainer (PHB)
- Entertainer Variant: Gladiator (PHB)
- Folk Hero (BR, PHB)
- Guild Artisan (PHB)
- Guild Artisan Variant: Guild Merchant (PHB)
- Hermit (PHB)
- Noble (BR, PHB)
- Noble Variant: Knight (PHB)
- Outlander (PHB)
- Sage (BR, PHB)
- Sailor (PHB)
- Sailor Variant: Pirate (PHB)
- Soldier (BR, PHB)
- Urchin (PHB)
- City Watch (SCAG)
- Clan Crafter (SCAG)
- Cloistered Scholar (SCAG)
- Courtier (SCAG)
- Faction Agent
- Far Traveler (SCAG)
- Inheritor (SCAG)
- Knight of the Order (SCAG)
- Mercenary Veteran (SCAG)
- Urban Bounty Hunter (SCAG)
- Uthgardt Tribe Member (SCAG)
- Waterdhavian Noble (SCAG)

Also worth noting is that D&D Adventurer's League [supports](http://dndadventurersleague.org/faq-12-12/) customizing a background, as per the [PHB rules for doing so](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/personality-and-background#CustomizingaBackground). While this allows for a custom selection of skill proficiency and tool/language proficiency, you're still restricted to equipment packages and background features as published.

#### Backgrounds from D&D adventures and other products

- Cult of the Dragon Infiltrator (HotDQ, RoT)
- Dragon Scholar (HotDQ, RoT)
- Deep Delver (OotA)
- Underdark Experience (OotA)
- Haunted One (CoS)
- Anthropologist (ToA)
- Archaeologist (ToA)
- Fisher (GoS)
- Marine (GoS)
- Shipwright (GoS)
- Smuggler (GoS)
- Faceless (BGDiA)
- Feylost (TWBtW)
- Witchlight Hand (TWBtW)
- Heretic (*Ruins of Mezro*)
- Detective (*Rats of Waterdeep*)
- Tavern Worker (*Durnan's Guide to Tavernkeeping*)
- Tavern Regular (*Durnan's Guide to Tavernkeeping*)
- Arctic Guide (*Knuckleheads*)
- Cold Water Fisherfolk (*Knuckleheads*)
- Goliath Seeker (*Knuckleheads*)
- Prospector (*Knuckleheads*)
- Skald (*Knuckleheads*)
- Survivor (*Knuckleheads*)
- Whaler (*Knuckleheads*)

In addition, *Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus* contains alternate features for all 13 of the PHB backgrounds.

---

#### Additional Material

> **MOONSHAE ISLES & BORDER KINGDOM CHARACTERS**
> If you’re participating in adventures set in either of these locations,
> you can use their respective products (found on the DMs Guild) to
> select a background for your character.
> [Rising Shadows-Moonshae Isles Regional Guide](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/248303/Moonshae-Isles-Regional-Guide?src=hottest_filtered&filters=45470_0_0_0_0_0_0_0)
> [The Border Kingdoms: A Forgotten Realms Campaign Supplement](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/244431/The-Border-Kingdoms-A-Forgotten-Realms-Campaign-Supplement?filters=45470_0_0_0_0_0_0_0)

---

The information for older editions can be found here:

- [v10.3](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/revisions/166793/9)
- [v9.2](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/revisions/166793/6)

Comment: Wouldn't this list just be identical to the one on [D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/backgrounds) (once it has the missing entries)?

Comment: @Someone_Evil Depends on if AL supports 100% of the backgrounds from sourcebooks. I assume Ravnica/Acq Inc backgrounds wouldn't be but don't know for sure.

Comment: @Someone_Evil Things like the Rick-and-Morty book, Ravnica, and Acquisitions Incorporated are not valid resources for DDAL play. As far as DDAL player should be concerned, they do not exist at all.

Comment: @bluemoon93 what about the season-specific backgrounds that have popped up a couple of times? (PoTA and definitely CoS, at least? Those books are at my office, where I can't go currently....) Are they still available as part of a +1, or did the season 8 re-work of all things AL toss those out?

Comment: @nitsua60 IIRC your Background never took up your +1, so you could pick it from any available source - you could pick XGtE as your +1 to play a Hexblade Warlock, and still pick a Background from the SCAG, for instance.

Comment: Also, there's content for the Adventurer's League that has additional backgrounds, but I think it might be season-dependent, and I don't think that there are any of them for the current season of play.

Comment: Here's the link to where to find the AL resources on D&D beyond: https://dnd.wizards.com/ddal_general including the V11 players guide as requested https://media.wizards.com/2021/dnd/downloads/DDAL_PlayersGuidev11_0.pdf

Comment: Got this mostly updated for v11. Got a couple things to review still.